# confirmation page before mailing in php

Tags: php, html, email

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [confirming message before mailing in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13301834/confirming-message-before-mailing-in-php)

I am developing a page where in my boss will search for a company in a database. Once he clicks on its name, an email format will be shown (done in html) as a confirmation page. And then there will be a button (or link? i'm still not sure which to use) which will then send the mail to that particular company.

```
<img src="../../img/emmlogo.jpg" style="left: 0;position: absolute; width: 75px;"/>
<body style="padding: 0 0 0 100px;position: relative;">
<?php echo date("F d, Y ");?>  <br><br>

<b> echo $row_Recordset1['First Name'].'&nbsp'.$row_Recordset1['Middle Initial'].'&nbsp'.$row_Recordset1['Last Name']; ?></b><br>
<?php echo $row_Recordset1 ['Position'].'<br>'.$row_Recordset1['Company Name'].'<br>'.$row_Recordset1['Corporate Address'];?><br><br>

<p>Dear <?php echo $row_Recordset1['Last Name']; ?>:</p>
```

I've only gotten to the confirmation page and it's all set. I just want to find out if it is possible that I can send the information without having to repeat the queries from the confirmation page that I made and I want the mail to look exactly as how I made the html. I am open to any comments or suggestions as this site has helped me a lot in developing this particular project. thank you

Comment: take the created html, that was shown, and post it to the sending page.

Comment: there weren't any clear answers and I just tried to make my question more clearly. If this violates any rule then closing this would be okay. thanks

Comment: I've edited and added the code. I'm having images in the code as well

Comment: Hi Jams, Might I suggest if you find you are always answered correctly after 2 tries, perhaps you could put more work into the first question, or try to rewrite the origional Question (click `edit`) rather than posting a similar question a second time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should get rid of relative paths for your pictures if you intend on sending this HTML... provide links to servers that are accessible to everybody.

What you can do is send an HTML email (plenty of libraries already do that for you). If you want to reuse directly your confirmation page, consider the usage of `ob_start` and `ob_end_clean`. In between these two calls, query your script that generates the preview and dump it into a buffer using `ob_get_contents`. This should save you from writing the code twice.

Here's sample code from one of my project:

```
ob_start(); // turn on output buffering
require("mails/email_preview.php"); // include, require, process whatever you want to fill the buffer with
$_body=ob_get_contents(); // get the content of the buffer
ob_end_clean(); // erase the buffer and turn off output buffering
                
$this->sendMail($_emailAddress, "Email Title", $_body);
```

Helpful links:

- [ob_start](https://www.php.net/ob_start)
- [ob_get_contents](https://www.php.net/ob_get_contents)
- [ob_end_clean](https://www.php.net/ob_end_clean)

Comment: can you refer to me a link of sample usage of this code? thanks!

Comment: hi emartel, thanks for all the help. i wish you could still help me further as i get errors along these lines:

<img src="../../img/emmlogo.jpg" style="left: 0;position: absolute; width: 75px;"/>
<body style="padding: 0 0 0 100px;position: relative;">
.date("F d, Y ").  <br><br>

<b>.$row_Recordset1['First Name'].&nbsp.$row_Recordset1['Middle Initial'].&nbsp.$row_Recordset1['Last Name'].</b><br>
.$row_Recordset1 ['Position'].<br>.$row_Recordset1['Company Name'].<br>.$row_Recordset1['Corporate Address'].<br><br>

<p>Dear <?php echo $row_Recordset1['Last Name']; ?>:</p>

Comment: How do you feed this to the code?  Be careful creating valid HTML (your first image is before the body, you don't have HTML tags and no head).  You can simply call the php file that generates your preview, it should give you the output you want

Comment: I'm not sure I can follow. Yes there are no html tags as I just copied my confirmation page to this page. oh and btw can i just test this code server side? the site's not launched yet and i'm not familiar with mailing using php yet. thanks alot for your help!

Comment: Should I use buttons or <a></a>?

Comment: Buttons or a are a matter of style, it's up to you. Store your confirmation in a proper php file and load it like in my example by changing the require statement