# PHP Output of a foreach included in a mail variable

Tags: php

I want to include the output of a foreach loop + echo $total as the variable $order in my sendmail.php. Can somebody help me? I am a bit stuck.

My sendmail.php:

```
<?php
if(!isset($_SESSION)) {
     session_start();
}

$to = $_SESSION['email'];
$firstname = $_SESSION['firstname'] ;
$lastname = $_SESSION['lastname'] ;
$email = $_SESSION['email'] ;
$addressline1 = $_SESSION['addressline1'] ;
$towncity = $_SESSION['towncity'] ;
$postcode = $_SESSION['postcode'] ;

foreach ($_SESSION['invoice'] as $value) { //needs to = $order
    echo $value."<br>";} //needs to = $order
echo "Total: $".$_SESSION['total']; //needs to = $order

//set subject
$subject = "Crystal Fusion - New Order";

//body of the e-mail
$body = "New Order Received:\n\n\n\n
    From: $firstname $lastname\n
    Email: $email\n
    Address: $addressline1\n
    Town/City: $towncity\n
    Postcode: $postcode\n
    Order: $order"; //needs to = foreach loop above

$sent = mail($to, $subject, $body);

if($sent)
    {echo "<script language=javascript>window.location = 'mail_succeed.php';</script>";}
else
    {echo "<script language=javascript>window.location = 'mail_fail.php';</script>";}
?>
```

Comment: I just answered to a very similar question:

[Sending mail using some PHP content][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13337970/confirmation-page-before-mailing-in-php/13338453#13338453

Answer (score 0):

The solution would be to use something along the lines of

```
ob_start(); 

// Add your output
foreach ($_SESSION['invoice'] as $value) { //needs to = $order
    echo $value."<br>";} //needs to = $order
echo "Total: $".$_SESSION['total']; //needs to = $order
// if you need your logic at multiple places, consider using a separate php file and including it here
// ...

$body=ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean(); 
mail($to, $subject, $body);
```

Answer (score -1):

How about changing your foreach loop to:

```
$order = '';
foreach ($_SESSION['invoice'] as $value) { //needs to = $order
    echo $value."<br>"; //needs to = $order
    $order .= $value."\n";
}
echo "Total: $".$_SESSION['total']; //needs to = $order
$order .= "Total: $".$_SESSION['total'];
```

Comment: I was about to post the same thing, you were just a little faster. I would only suggest you change the `<br>` at the end of `$order .= $value."<br>";` to `\n`

Comment: There is no need to duplicate the code, this will only create bugs in the long term as code gets changed!  The code can be isolated in another php file and included between ob_start and ob_end_clean calls

Comment: @emartel Bugs can come up anytime code is changed. This is just a simple solution for a relatively simple problem.

Comment: To me this is bad programming practice as it's very easy to change for a proper solution